# How Should the True Energy Gain of the NIF's "Scientific Breakeven" Fusion Experiment be Calculated?

Tags: mass-energy, fusion

According to [this article](https://www.energy.gov/articles/doe-national-laboratory-makes-history-achieving-fusion-ignition) "LLNL’s experiment surpassed the fusion threshold by delivering 2.05 megajoules (MJ) of energy to the target, resulting in 3.15 MJ of fusion energy output." It isn't super-clear from the news articles I've seen whether the energy generated *by fusion* was 3.15 MJ or was 3.15 MJ minus 2.05 MJ (that is, only 1.1 MJ). This [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility#cite_note-135) says that the "energy gain was about 1.5", suggesting that the author of that article believes that only 1.1 MJ of energy was generated by fusion.

I think that the true "energy gain" of the reaction (not accounting for the low efficiency of the lasers) was actually (2.05+3.15)/2.05 = 2.54.

There's a term called "fusion energy gain factor", or "Q", which is defined as the ratio of fusion power produced in a nuclear fusion reactor to the power required to maintain the reaction. This might be a misleading type of "gain factor" from an engineering perspective. In my experience, a "gain of 1" usually means that you get back exactly what you put in (ironically, you "gain" nothing).

What is the most technically correct method for fusion researchers to use when calculating and communicating "the gain" of their experiments, assuming that they wish to align with best practices in the broader field of physics?

Comment: Note, I just edited the referenced WIkipedia article.

Comment: It is a tremendously bad idea to edit an article when you are unsure of what the correction should be. I have undone your edit because your edit is just plain wrong. You have misunderstood what it is.

Comment: Actually, I researched the topic thoroughly and I do not think I made a mistake. I would appreciate it if you would restore the edits that you reverted. If you still think you're correct, I am, of course, willing to discuss this here. If I agree, I'll update the edits myself.

Comment: If you have researched the topic thoroughly, you would not have mistaken what the gain factor is, what the meaning of the press release was, what the definition of gain elsewhere in physics and engineering was, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of gain simply includes the input energy. The threshold for breakthrough is 1.

The version you are thinking of is called excess energy, and its breakthrough is at 0.

The correct gain calculation is $$Q=\frac{\text{Input+Output Energies}}{\text{Input Energy}}=\frac{3.15}{2.05}=1.54$$

The excess energy is 1.1 MJ, i.e. excess gain is 0.54.

Everybody uses the definition of gain in which 1 is the breakthrough.

Comment: This response simply redefines the fusion energy term "fusion energy gain factor", or Q. But I believe that the formula that you used above is incorrect. You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_energy_gain_factor. In any case, this topic is not about how the fusion community is currently defining its own term, it's about whether this use of the term "gain" is consistent with its use in the broader fields of physics and engineering. The fusion community has been criticized in the past for redefining terms to make their achievements sound more impressive in press releases.

Comment: @phil1008 I work for a competitor to them. The definition of gain used in fusion industry is in agreement with the gain defined in electronics. And there is no reason why it should be insisted that there should be agreement in the definitions; it is merely nice to have. You are just wrong.

Comment: Ok, let's use your formula above. If I make a reactor, say from an old Easy-bake oven, and I discover using a Watt-o-meter that it consumes 60W, and I somehow measure the output energy and discover that the Easy-bake oven's total output energy is also, surprise, surprise, 60W, then by your formula, my Easy-bake oven will have a "Q" of (60+60)/60 = 2. Therefore, I just beat the NIF results with an Easy-bake oven. Alternately, if we define "output energy" to mean "energy produced by fusion" then the easy-bake oven has a Q of (60+0)/60 = 1, which means it still "achieved breakeven".

Comment: No, it will just get Q=1. There is no part of it converting mass into energy and so there is no excess output power. And this is what NIF announcement is also correctly getting. It is 1.54 not 2.54.

Comment: Since you said above, "Everybody uses the definition of gain in which 1 is the breakthrough." and you said "...it will just get Q=1", do you also assert that the Easy-bake oven achieves breakthrough? How do you explain why all the fusion experiments before the NIF were not able to announce that they achieved scientific break even?

Comment: Because we are all trying to get the system to achieve fusion, not just directly convert energy into heat. When you actually try to achieve something, there will be losses. Breakeven is not so simple.

Comment: I give up. You should watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOQowCeAnRs&ab_channel=Newsthink

Comment: What are you even on about? That is now a standard prob and stats topic to cover, and completely irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: @phil1008 - "The fusion community has been criticized in the past for redefining terms to make their achievements sound more impressive in press releases" - as the author of the wikipedia article you are quoting to support your claim: **no, you are wrong**.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Ref: "On 2013/8/7, LLNL announced that ... it had achieved scientific breakeven in the NIF. In this experiment, Pfus was approximately 14 kJ, while the laser output was 1.8 MJ. By their previous definition, this would be a Q of 0.0077. For this press release, they re-defined Q once again, this time equating Pheat to be only the amount energy delivered to "the hottest portion of the fuel", calculating that only 10 kJ of the original laser energy reached the part of the fuel that was undergoing fusion reactions. This release has been heavily criticized in the field."